# Codeigniter Data Passing

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

Controller Name: mother.php

Controller Function:

```
public function mother_dram_print() {

    $mother = array();

    $mother['label'] = $this->load->view('mother/mother_dram', '', TRUE);

    $data = array(

        'name_1' => $this->input->post('name_1'),

        'size_1' => $this->input->post('size_1'),

        'qty_1' => $this->input->post('qty_1')

    );

    $data['label_print'] = $this->load->view('print_template', $mother, TRUE);

    $this->load->view('home', $data);
}
```

View File Name: mother_dram.php

View File:

```
<div class="moth-dram-label-main-container fix">

<?php

for ($p1 = 1; $p1 <= $qty_1; $p1++) {

    echo "<div class='moth-dram-label-wrapper fix'>";

    echo "<div class='moth-dram-name fix'>$name_1</div>";

    echo "<div class='moth-dram-ml'>$size_1</div>";

    echo "</div>";

}

</div>
```

Note: when I am submitted data from html form data can't view in mother_dram.php file.

Comment: you aren't passing in any data to it, unless youre reading from the post array directly there, which is kind of hacky

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define your `$data` before you pass it into `$this->load->view('mother/mother_dram', $data, TRUE);`

From the style of your code, it looks like you think that `$data` is passed along views as long as you define it somewhere, but this isn't the case.